Word find/replace Paragraph mark deletes list number
I have a numbered list in Word:
1.  Lorem
2.  ipsum
    1 dolor


The second list item is split into two paragraphs. This happens in PDF to Word conversions when a digit is present at the line beginning. I want to merge them using Find and Replace:
Find what: ^13([0-9])
Replace with:  \1
✓ Use wildcards
Applying Replace, the merged paragraph loses its list number.

How can I prevent the loss of list numbers?

MS word stores paragraph-level formatting information with the paragraph mark. If you make the paragraph mark go away, you make the related formatting go away as well.

In MS Word it was possible to replace a specific entry without regex like this: (or similar)


In most modern offices like MS or Libre you can do similar by Macro goto start of 1 dolor and backspace twice to replace the 2nd Pilcrow and add a space or delete forwards from a space after end of Ipsum 
However My Word does not allow unsecure macros so I have to do it the last century way.


Thanks. This seems correct although it does not exactly answer my specific need. I take from it that I have to either replace manually or create a macro (which, however, needs to ask for confirmation of each replacement).
